# render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer' - DateTimePicker - Django 1.11 -> 3.1 migration

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, django-1.11, django-3.1

I have the following issue with the form

forms.py

```
class PublicHolidayForm(forms.ModelForm):
        date = forms.DateField(label='Date', required=True, widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD"}),input_formats=["%Y-%m-%d"])
        description = forms.CharField(label='Description',  max_length=250, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':50}))
        class Meta:
            model = PublicHoliday
            fields = ("date","description")
```

whereby

```
date = forms.DateField(label='Date', required=True, widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD"}),input_formats=["%Y-%m-%d"])
```

causes the problem

```
render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'
```

How can i resolve this ?

I think its something to do with

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/

```
Support for Widget.render() methods without the renderer argument is removed.
```